# Choregraphe how to create application that offers to choose from multiple applications

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

I'm new to choregraphe and NAO. I'm working on different meditation exercises, that NAO guides the user through and I want to have one "Master application" that introduces the different exercises and let's the user choose, which one they want to do.

How do I implement an application switch in Choregraphe?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an application that lists all the other applications, by calling [`ALPackageManager.packages2`](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao6/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-core/packagemanager/packagemanager-api#PackageManager::packages2) and going through the results.
You have to spot packages that provide behaviors of nature "Interactive".
You can get their human-readable names to populate a graphical menu.
You can get their trigger sentences to populate a dialogue-based menu.

When an app is selected, use [`ALAutonomousLife.switchFocus`](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao6/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-interaction-engines/alautonomouslife/alautonomouslife-0#ALAutonomousLifeProxy::switchFocus) to leave your launcher app and start the other app. Make sure the [launch conditions](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao6/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-interaction-engines/alautonomouslife/launch-trigger) of your launcher app leads to restarting it if a user is still around when the other app finishes.